# Several books have the same name in the database, how to return only one name, using JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Uma query está assi:

```
@Query("select l.tipo_registro from LivroEntity l where l.nome =:nome")
    String findFirstByLivroPorNome(String nome);
```

I need to validate a business rule like: if type_registration is different, and the name is igaul, do not register:

```
String tipo_registro="";
         tipo_registro = livroRepository.findFirstByLivroPorNome(livro.getNome());
        System.out.println(tipo_registro);
        if(!tipo_registro.equals("") && !tipo_registro.equals(livro.getTipo_registro())){
            throw new CadastroException("Não pode ter 2 Livros com nomes iguais (" + livro.getNome() + ") E Tipo de Registros diferentes (" +
                    livro.getTipo_registro() + ") Diferente de (" + tipo_registro + ")");
        }
        return livro /*livroRepository.save(livro)*/;
```

Comment: Please ask questions in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `@Query` annotation. Spring Data automatically create the query based on the name of the method. It would be like this:

```
LivroEntity findFirstByNome(String nome);
```

Your bussiness rule would be:

```
LivroEntity livro = livroRepository.findFirstByNome(livro.getNome());
String tipo_registro = livro != null ? livro.getTipoRegistro() : "";
System.out.println(tipo_registro);
if(!tipo_registro.equals("") && !tipo_registro.equals(livro.getTipo_registro())){
        throw new CadastroException("Não pode ter 2 Livros com nomes iguais (" + livro.getNome() + ") E Tipo de Registros diferentes (" +
                livro.getTipo_registro() + ") Diferente de (" + tipo_registro + ")");
}
return livro /*livroRepository.save(livro)*/;
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly that, it worked for my case.